# How to make a smooth oval window

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Here is a simple model that I'm working on:

[image]

I want to make the selected ring of edges smooth, to get rid of the discrete angles and get an oval shape. Something like this:

[image]

I have tried applying subdiv modifier but that changes its shape to a multi-point star. Also it smooths outer edge of the cube too, which I do not want. I have also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, but that does work on the selected face, only on the outer faces. Lastly I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, which only changes the size of this face but doesn't do the smoothing that I want.

Comment: can you upload an image of your multipoint star? can you elaborate why cegaton's workflow didn't suffice?

Comment: I didn't say cegaton's workflow didn't work. I just checked it and it works.

Comment: You can try "subdivide smooth" in edit mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a combination of [**Subsurf Modifier**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html?highlight=subsurf%20modifier), [**Smooth shading**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html?highlight=shade%20smooth#smooth) and [**Edge Crease**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?highlight=crease#edge-crease)

---

Start wit a plane.

Subdivide it.

Select some vertices to create the outline of the window.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (to activate the "To Sphere" tool)

Move the mouse a bit to create a rough oval.

Add the middle vertices to the selection and extrude the shape of the window.

Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to add a subsurf modifier with two subdivisions.

In edit mode set the object to smooth shading.

To make the outside edges sharp, enter edit mode, select the vertices on the edge of the object and mark a crease (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) with a value of 1, so that the edges are sharp.

[image]

Comment: Thanks cegaton. That works, so I'll accept the answer. However, I was looking for a way of doing this on existing mesh, as shown in my first image. Can we make an existing edge loop smoother?

Comment: Just skip the first 6 steps, use subsurf, smooth shading, then mark the eges you want sharp and set the crease value.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest entering edit mode, switching to edge selection (CTRL+TAB from the 3D View, or one of the boxes next to transform orientation), and selecting the outer edge of the circular window. From there, within the 3D viewport, hit CTRL+B for beveling.

You'll note that moving the mouse will scale a face where the edge used to be. By rolling the mouse wheel, you can change the number of edges within it. Scale it up to four or five, and you should have a satisfactory rounding of the edge.

(As a side note, the reason that CTRL+R doesn't work is that it only operates on quads; and your inner face is not four sided, it's twelve sided. So that won't help you here.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it does actually create faces around the outer boundary, but those "edge loops" still have the same number of vertices as the original edge loop, so it is not getting any smoother or roundish. I tried creating more faces too (using scroll wheel), but that only creates more loops, with the same number of vertices and same angles between consecutive vertices.